# Finding argument of $z^4 + 1 = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

How can I find the argument of $z^4 = -1$? This means the imaginary part is $0$ and the real part is $(-1)^{\frac{1}{4}}$. The principle argument is the angle from the real axis so the line from the point to the origin.

$(-1)^{\frac{1}{4}} = \sqrt{i}$. So $z = 0 + \sqrt{i}$. So.. shouldn't the principle argument be $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: $z^4=-1$ is an equation, not a number.  $(-1)^{1/4}$ is not a uniquely defined number either.  Hence neither has an argument.  A *solution* to $z^4=-1$ has an argument.

Comment: OP: You have *a* valid value for $z$, whose argument is *not* $\pi/2$: the possible values of $\sqrt{i}$ are complex, not merely imaginary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the equation $z^4 = -1$. See both sides as complex numbers (both having an argument and a module).

Let $r$ be the module of $z$ and let $\theta$ be it's argument, i.e. $z = re^{i\theta}$. We've got $z^4 = (re^{i\theta})^4 = r^4 e^{i 4\theta}$.

Now the module of $-1$ is easy to find : it's 1. It's argument is $\pi + 2n \pi$ since if you rotate 1 by an angle $\pi + 2n \pi$  you end up on -1 (keep in mind that a rotation of $2\pi$ is a full rotation, so you are free to perform as many as you like in whatever direction you like (clockwise or anti-clockwise) which means that a rotation by $2n \pi$ for any integer $n$ is harmless). Therefore we can write $-1$ as $1e^{i(\pi+2n \pi)}$.

Since $z^4$ is equal to $-1$, both their module and their argument must be equal. That is to say $r^4 = 1$ and $e^{i4\theta} = e^{i(\pi+2n\pi)}$. This means that $r = 1$ and $4\theta = \pi + 2n \pi$. Hence $\theta = \frac{\pi+2n \pi}{4}$. Note that there only is 4 values of $n$ that leads to original values of $\theta$, namely $n = 0, 1,  2, 3$. The corresponding values of $\theta$ are $\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{7\pi}{4}$.

All other values of $n$ lead to values of $\theta$ which are similar to those listed above modulo one of a few full rotation.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $z^4+1=0$ has exactly four complex solutions. You can think about

$z^4+1=(z^2+i)(z^2-i)=(z+i\sqrt{i})(z-i\sqrt{i})(z+\sqrt{i})(z-i\sqrt{i})$

Can you find the arguments of the solutions of $z^4+1=0$ from the last expression?

Comment: What was wrong with what I said?

Comment: As @vadim123 said, finding the argument of $z^4+1=0$ doesn't make any sense. As I mentioned above, you have four solutions to that *equation* each one with a different argument.

Answer (score 0):

The imaginary part of $-1$ is equal to $0$, because it "lies" on the real line, hence its corresponding angle is $\pi$.
If you want to solve $z^4 = -1$. The roots can be obtained by converting $-1$ to its polar form, and the roots are given by  $w_{k} = 1^{1/4}(\cos(\frac{\pi + 2\pi k}{4} + i\sin(\frac{\pi + 2\pi k}{4}))$. Where $1$ is its radius, $4$ stands for the polynomial degree and $k=0,1,2,3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$z^4+1=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z^4=-1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z^4=e^{\pi i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\left(e^{\left(\pi+2\pi k\right) i}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=e^{\frac{\left(\pi+2\pi k\right) i}{4}}$$

With $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k:0-3$

So the solutions are:

$$z_0=e^{\frac{\left(\pi+2\pi\cdot 0\right) i}{4}}=e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}$$
$$z_1=e^{\frac{\left(\pi+2\pi\cdot 1\right) i}{4}}=e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4}}$$
$$z_2=e^{\frac{\left(\pi+2\pi\cdot 2\right) i}{4}}=e^{-\frac{3\pi i}{4}}$$
$$z_3=e^{\frac{\left(\pi+2\pi\cdot 3\right) i}{4}}=e^{-\frac{\pi i}{4}}$$

---

So the argument of the answers is:

$$\arg(z_0)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$\arg(z_1)=\frac{3\pi}{4}$$
$$\arg(z_2)=-\frac{3\pi}{4}$$
$$\arg(z_3)=-\frac{\pi}{4}$$